# How do I override an entity view controller?

Tags: 8, commerce, routes

I am trying to override the entity view controller for a commerce product view, so that I can  redirect the user based on certain conditions.

I am trying to do this through the RouteSubscriber::alterRoutes implementation.

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.commerce_product.canonical')) {
      $route->addDefaults(['_controller' => '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ProductViewController::view']);
    }
  }

}
```

My custom controller is acknowledged, but I'm getting the following error:

> RuntimeException: Controller "Drupal\mymodule\Controller\ProductViewController::view()" requires that you provide a value for the "$_entity" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one. in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ArgumentResolver->getArguments() (line 78 of /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php).

My ProductViewController extends the Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityViewController.

```
class ProductViewController extends EntityViewController {

  public function view(EntityInterface $_entity, $view_mode = 'full')
  {
    return parent::view($_entity, $view_mode); 
  }

}
```

Can anyone tell what additional route context parameters I need to add to get this working?

Comment: Can you add the code from your controller?

Comment: @sonfd Currently the controller only has the override method (nothing in it), but I will add it.  I believe this error is occurring because the route configuration is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be unsetting some things in your alterRoutes method doing it the way you are. (However, I can't tell if or why that's happening after looking at [Route::addDefaults()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21Route.php/function/Route%3A%3AaddDefaults/8.2.x).)

I'm doing the same thing for a media entity's route. My alterRoutes method is a little different - I'm using [Route::setDefault()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21routing%21Route.php/function/Route%3A%3AsetDefault/8.2.x).

```
public function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
  if ($route = $collection->get('entity.media.canonical')) {
    $route->setDefault('_controller', '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\MyController::view');
  }
}
```

Additionally, the variable names in your controller methods are important - they must match the variable name from the route definition. See the documentation for [Using parameters in routes](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/parameters-in-routes/using-parameters-in-routes#s-example)

> In most PHP code the name of the variable does not matter but here it does: **the name of the method argument must match the slug**. Conversely, if the method argument name matches the name of the slug, the parameter will be passed in, irrespective of the order of arguments.

Comment: I get the same error with setDefault.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  The problem was the argument name.  Once I changed $_entity to $commerce_product in the controller::view method it started working.

```
class ProductViewController extends EntityViewController {

  public function view(EntityInterface $commerce_product, $view_mode = 'full')
  {
    return parent::view($commerce_product, $view_mode); 
  }

}
```

I figured this out by looking for other classes that extend EntityViewController and I found NodeViewController and the variable name was the only significant difference.

Such specific variable naming conventions is a bit *unconventional* imxp, but I believe I have seen this is other places in this Drupal 8.

Anyway, thanks for the assistance @sonfd and I hope this helps others.

Comment: Oh woops, I just updated my answer with the same stuff.